# Make table height 100% without css

Tags: html, layout, html-table

I got a task to make a table layout like we in 1997, without any css at all, and i got stuck with setting main table a 100% `height`. So, without any style attributes only with tools available in 1997, how i can make it?
I found out a working solution for modern browsers - deleting `DOCTYPE`, but it is obviously a hack.
Setting body and html `height="100%"` also doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `width` and `height` properties of a `<table>` are **not** supported in HTML5. So you're going to need to remove the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration from your mark up in any case. Or use CSS.

Given you said that you can't use CSS, then ensure that you have removed that `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration from your mark up and then you can set the height of your `<table>` as follows:

```
<table height="100%">
```

This should do the job for you!

Comment: Thanks, but i already found out this. But maybe it have any better solution? Because, it will broke in any 1997 browser

Comment: Just out of curiosity why does it have to stick so strictly to 1997 standards? What browser are you testing this against?